# In MS Access I need to look up a record and use it as a 'Control Source' for a report

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

My situation is that I need to pull an additional name for a report. The name I need has to match a specific employee ID .

I read that I could use **`=DLookup()`** to do this but I am getting a problem. 
Here is my current attempt at solving this problem.

I set up a query called [EE Query] with the contents

```
SELECT Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName 
FROM Employees WHERE (((Employees.ID)=[Escalations].[EE]));
```

In my report I used the following as my control source in the desired field 
**`"=DLookUp([FirstName],[EE Query])"`**

So when I run my report, I get an input box that asks me to enter a value for `"EE Query"`. I find this strange as that isn't a parameter.
 So I assumed maybe I messed up and it was asking for a value for `[Escalations].[EE]` however when I entered the ID for the desired EE, my `textbox shows "#Error"`

I do not know where I went wrong.

Also if it helps here is my Record Source for the report, keep in mind that the FirstName field in this refers to a TSE and not to the needed EE.

```
SELECT [Report Query].DateTime, [Report Query].EscalationNeed, 
[Report Query].EscalationOutcome, Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, 
[Report Query].TSE, [Report Query].EE
FROM Employees INNER JOIN [Report Query] 
ON Employees.[ID] = [Report Query].[TSE];
```

[Escalations] [Employees] [Titles] are all tables.
Access 2010

Comment: Your quotes are confused.

Comment: What you want to do is very common. But it is as a control source for a textbox, not the whole report. Sometimes you need to look up a customer address (for example) when the report's recordsource includes only the customer code. Instead of building a more complex recordsource which includes a Join to find the address, a simple DLookup works nicely. The other common case is where you need to show something on the report which comes from the Form that issues the DoCmd.OpenReport. Sorry, enough rambling, ***what is [Escalations]*** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not solved the actual problem but I changed my DB design so that it is easier to work with in access.

To do this I created a separate table for the EE and TSE type employees so that I could easily include the names of each in the record source for my report. I then set the needed boxes to the now available Control Source fields for the EE name.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different solutions

**SOLUTION 1 - in VBA**

---

This solution can be useful if you need to create text box dynamically.
In the Form_Open event add this 3 lines of code

```
Dim s As String
s = "=DLookup(""FirstName"",""Employees"",""(Employees.ID)=[Escalations].[EE]"")"
txtYourTextBox.ControlSource = s
```

**SOLUTION 2 - Directly in the interface**

---

Set ControlSource property of your control to =DLookup("FirstName";"Employees";"Employes.ID=Escalations.EE")

**WARNING**

Please, note that there is a fundamental difference (:-() when you use VBA and the interface: the separator between the arguments in the 1st case is comma (,), in the 2nd case is the semicolomn (;).

Comment: So I tried solution two in a few ways.

`=DLookup("FirstName";"Employees";"Employees.ID=Escalations.EE")`
This produces a syntax error.

`=DLookup("FirstName","Employees","Employees.ID=Escalations.EE")`
This works syntactically but still produces "#Error" as it's output.

`=DLookup("FirstName","Employees","Employees.ID=[Report Query].EE")`
Also produces "#Error" as output.

`=DLookup("FirstName","Employees","Employees.EE")`
Produces blank output, but gives no error.

Comment: Also tried solution 1.
`Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim s As String
s = "=DLookup(""FirstName"",""Employees"",""(Employees.ID)=[Escalations].[EE]"")"
Text14.ControlSource = s

Dim s2 As String
s2 = "=DLookup(""LastName"",""Employees"",""(Employees.ID)=[Escalations].[EE]"")"
Text16.ControlSource = s2
End Sub`
Both boxes show output "#Error"

Comment: I tried both solution in Access 2010. Which version are using. Sorry, I forgot to ask this prior to post a solution for you but I took it as an assumption cause I was looking at the tag.

Comment: Ok. Let's try step by step.
I think where I made a mistake (if so it's a very silly mistake but let's go on...). Just to explain. I focused on the ControlSource property that, up to now, I didn't use in a report. 
The problem should be that all fields that are passed as arguments to the function must be defined. he report underlaying the report should

Comment: [Escalations].[EE] is not known as in the report should be known only as EE (there's no ambiguity cause it's the only field named EE).
If you want to eliminate the ambiguity you can insert an alias clause (e.g. AS EErpt) in the record source.

Can you try if with these correction the solution work?

Comment: I entered the following `=DLookup("FirstName","Employees","Employees.ID=EE")` and also tried `=DLookup("FirstName","Employees","EE")` which both output #Error.     Also tried `=DLookUp("FirstName","Employees",[Employees].[ID]=[EE])` and `=DLookUp("FirstName","Employees",[EE])` which both resulted in a new output of "#Name?"

Comment: Let's try to split the problem in small slices until we find what's wrong.
First:
 1) =DLookup("FirstName","Employees","EE") is wrong 'cause "EE" is not a condition. 
 2) =DLookUp("FirstName","Employees",[Employees].[ID]=[EE]) is wrong because the lack of double quotes (")
 3) =DLookUp("FirstName","Employees",[EE]) is a combination of 1) & 2).

Comment: When I've a problem like this normally I try with a fix value:

Comment: 1) use a formula like 


=DLookup("FirstName","Employees","Employees.ID=nn")


where nn is a value for Employees.ID


2) If 1) works, the problem is with EE so we need to get the desired value. 

This can be done using a variable that can be easily printed out. 

So if the value exists, you should show it using a simple msgbox me.EE if the recordsource is the query at the top of the post.

Let me know.

Comment: So yes, testing with the ID directly works. And yes the query at the top is my record source. As this exposes the ID I need as "EE" in the record source drop down, is there a way i can access this as part of the control source statement?

Comment: So the Control Source expression builder uses [EE] when I select it from the Escalations Report field list. However this returns a blank line as if the ID is not pulled. Running the report query by itself and looking at the returned results does in fact show the ID under the EE column.

Comment: Well I'm glad that at least some things start to work:-)

Comment: Now the problem left should be accessing the EE value from report available fields.

Let's summarize what we have up to now

1 - Dlookup works. 
2 - The problem is getting the EE field.

I can't really exactly understand what's happening but let me ask some questions.

Where is the ID in your query? I can't see it in the SELECT statement. You can use it for JOIN condition because you are running the query but when you try to use the result query it will become not available. EE is included in the query.

Comment: I'm looking at the query but I can't really understand what you're trying to do and I'm wondering if, regardless the technical problem, it is the right query. 
Can you explain what you're trying to do? Do you think this can help me to understand and to help you?

Comment: Okay no problem. So I am trying to make a report that is generated with three pieces of information to filter the results. That is the  two dates for the time period that you need and the employee you wish to select the information from. Each report entry should have the time/date, the TSE(a type of employee) that needed an escalation, a description of the need for escalation, a result of the escalation and the EE(another type of employee) that helped in the escalation.

Comment: There are three tables. [Escalations] [Employees] [Titles]. Titles holds two fields, the ID of the entry and the title name (e.g. TSE or EE). The Employees table holds four fields, the ID of the employee, the ID of that employees title, the first name and the last name of the employee. And the Escalation table holds 6 fields, the ID of the entry, the date/time of the entry, the reason for escalation [EscalationNeed], the result [EscalationOutcome], the ID of the TSE escalating and the ID of the EE responding.